# Access dataGridView in a Class Method Where it Does Not have Scope

Tags: c#

I want to access "dataGridView1" inside the method "GetApplicationName" which itself is inside the class "ExternalApplication". (The class and method names are not descriptive) "v" would correspond to a row in "dataGridView1", after casting "v" from string to an int I want to use it to select and highlight a row in that dataview. But inside that method "dataGridView1" is out of scope. I think doing the above is easier then the opposite - trying to make "v" the equivalent of global which seems to require more work(?) Not sure.  The code cited works so far...I have tried many things but can't get it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace houseDB1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        private MySqlConnection connection;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ExternalApplication();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("127.0.0.1/box3.php");

            server = "localhost";
            database = "realestate_db";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `ID`, `lat` , `long` FROM `house` ", connection);

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class ExternalApplication
        {
            public void GetApplicationName(string v) // getting values from webbrowser
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ZZTOP" + v);
                //return "The application";

            }
        }

        private void splitContainer1_Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass reference of `dataGridView1` to `GetApplicationName` method.

Comment: If I do: public void GetApplicationName(string v, DataGrid dataGridView1 )  Is that what you meant? That causes a run time error "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument". The call is from a web page - knows nothing about datagrid. And sorry if I didn't know enough C# to do the code you meant...

Comment: Try to make `dataGridView1` as a static member and then access `dataGridView1` directly from your nested class. If that doesn't work then pass instance of outer class to the nested class and then with that instance, access the members of outer class inside nested class.